# Use namedSize in onplatform using XAML

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use an specific size to the font of an label for each platform using exclusively XAML. This code works fine:

```
<Label x:Name="DescricaoLabel"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
               Text="{Binding Descricao}"
               TextColor="#426d76">
            <Label.Font>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Font"
                            Android="14"
                            iOS="Micro" />
            </Label.Font>
</Label>
```

However, the tag `Label.Font` is marked as obsolete. I tried this:

```
<Label.FontSize>
         <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                         Android="14"
                         iOS="Micro" />
</Label.FontSize>
```

But using the tag `Label.FontSize` I was unable to compile because of the use of the NamedSize 'Micro'.

What is the best way to use double and also NamedSize within XAML and without make use of an obsolete tag?

Answer (score 3):

The type needs to be of the same type. You cannot have both named size and double together in the default one.

The NamedSize works via an inbuilt static converter. You can write your own converter, maybe taking both as string and then converting. Or use a converter with parameter and specify the value and type.

The default one doesn't handle the scenario you are trying to achieve.

```
public class StringToSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    {
        double size;
        if(double.TryParse(value.ToString, out size))
        {
            //this is a double
            return size;            
        }    
        // its a named size, so convert the named size to enum
       NamedSize namedSize;
       if (Enum.TryParse(value.ToString, true, out namedSize))
       {
            return Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Default, typeof(Label));
       }    
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can read more about Converters below :

- [Bindings and Collections](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/)
- [How do I use IValueConverters?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18849/how-do-i-use-ivalueconverters)

Another alternative approach is to define a named label style in your app.cs or app.xaml.cs with the font size set and using that style in your XAML. In that case you need not use OnPlatform in XAML, it will be in your CS file.

Comment: could you please give some code using an converter? I can't see how could I use this solution.

Comment: I have added a sample pseudo code for what i explained.

Comment: I tried hard to use onPlatform and converter but seems that there are problems in this approach. I couldn't test this yet...

Comment: I have added one more approach without OnPlatform in xaml